# Is OK to delete the MySQL database files directly on the server?

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

So, I need to free up some space on our database server.

On investigation it looks like lots of space is being taken up by MariaDB/MySQL databases that are no longer used (snapshots and defunct applications). I want to delete those, but due to events, nobody here has access to a MariaDB user account which can drop those database schemas.

MariaDB is running on the server, running a live system.

Can I just go into the /mysql folder and delete the redundant data from the filesystem without it messing up the live database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this might work without immediate problems, this is a very bad idea. Don't do this. MySQL expects to have full control over its data directories.

Instead, if you have lost root access, schedule a maintenance window and reset the root password for MySQL and afterwards, drop the database properly.